# shadow not showing in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
         super.awakeFromNib()

       makeRoundedCorners()

        cellBackGroundView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cellBackGroundView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
        cellBackGroundView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        cellBackGroundView.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        cellBackGroundView.clipsToBounds = true
        cellBackGroundView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    }
```

I am trying above code but shadow is not showing, not getting what is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are applying rounded corner and shadow both to a single view.

You should apply the rounded corner to the first view, and shadow to another view which is the superview of the first view.

For example, If cellBackGroundView is the subView of cell. then You should apply the rounded corner to cellBackGroundView and the shadow to cell(Which is the superView of cellBackGroundView).

```
    addShadowToView(view: cell, value: 3)
    addCornerToView(view: cell.cellBackGroundView, value: 8)
```

Let me share my functions with you,

For Shadow,

```
func addShadowToView (view : UIView, value: CGFloat) {
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: value, height: value)
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    view.clipsToBounds = false
}
```

For Rounded Corner,

```
func addCornerToView (view : UIView, value: CGFloat) {
    view.layer.cornerRadius = value
    view.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove `clipsToBounds = true` attribute

```
  self.shadowColor = color.cgColor
  self.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 1.4)
  self.shadowOpacity = opacity
  self.shadowRadius = 0.0
  self.masksToBounds = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i use for shadows:

```
extension UIView {
   func addShadow(color: UIColor, shadowRadius: CGFloat, opacity: Float) {
      layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
      layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
      layer.shadowOffset = .zero
      layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
      layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
      layer.shouldRasterize = true
      layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
}}
```

Usage:

```
view.addShadow(color: UIColor.black, shadowRadius: 4, opacity: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one for collectionViewshadow

```
class CollectionViewCornerRound: UICollectionView {

var viewCornerRadius: CGFloat = 10 {
    didSet {
        layoutSubviews()
    }
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layer.shadowRadius = 2
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    layer.cornerRadius = viewCornerRadius
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    clipsToBounds = true
  }
}
```